# How can I assign a value to an excel table based on date range in another excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a named table (DateGroup) that denotes specific groupings of dates that are named and can be changed by a user:

```
  Group Name  | Start Date | End Date    
  Proj 1      | 10/1/2020  | 12/31/2020    
  Proj 1 Eval | 1/1/2021   | 1/15/2021
```

Another table has data that we would like to assign to a group based on that first table:

```
Activity |  Hours | Date        | Group    
Act 1    | 10     | 10/15/2020  | Proj 1    
Act 2    | 10     | 10/30/2020  | Proj 1     
Act 3    | 5      | 1/15/2021   | Proj 1 Eval
```

Is there a formula that could find the appropriate row assign the value or is there a way to accomplish this in power query?

Comment: 1. why is `Act 3` in group `Proj 1 Eval`? as that date is not in the range. 2. can the dates overlap?

Comment: that was a typo -- Act 3 should be 2021.  Dates in the group table cannot overlap -- and I could reformat the table to only have the start date if that would make the lookup easier.  I'm going to explore that a bit and see if I can find any solutions there.

Comment: Index Match on the start date then should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Scotts comment above, I reformatted the group table and omitted the end date as:

```
Start Date   |  Group Name
```

after that a vlookup formula  `=VLOOKUP([@RowDate],DateGroups,2,TRUE)` returned the group name appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In table 1 make Group Name the right most columns, and use vlookup formula in another table

=vlookup([@date],table2,2)